# Is there a single-cell formula to count the total number of rows that are completely filled with a value?

Tags: checkbox, count, sum, google-sheets-formula, sequence

I'm looking for an elegant solution to remove the helper column `G` such that I have a formula in located in a single cell which counts the total number of rows completely filled with a uniform value (in this case `TRUE`). In the example image below, this would be `2` as displayed in cell `I1`.

[image]

Currently the helper column `G` is successfully determining the state of if a row is completely filled with a uniform value on a row-by-row basis. This helper column is then used to count the number of true values from column `G` to provide the final answer in cell `I1`.

Current Formulae:

`G` -> `=IF(COUNT('Sheet1'!A1:E1)=0, ,(ArrayFormula(SUM(IF({A1:E1}=TRUE,1,0)))=COUNT('Sheet1'!A1:E1)))`

`I` -> `=COUNTIF(G1:G5,TRUE)`

I'm assuming there is some form of array function I can use to condense column `G` into the single cell that forms the final answer I currently have in cell `I1`, without having to use a helper column; however I'm struggling to find or apply it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(MMULT(A1:E5*1, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:E5), 1, 1, )), COLUMNS(A1:E5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Awesome question. Though the previous solution does provide the same result, this can also be achieved using a simplified filter() nested inside of a counta():

Example:
[image: Spreadsheet with below formula selected]

Formula text:
`=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, A:A=true, B:B=true, C:C=true, D:D=true, E:E=true))`